# Removing a part of the URL with .htaccess. 404 after rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am all confused with my rewrite. I want to do the following:

- example.com/**not/needed**/index.php → example.com/index.php
- example.com/**not/needed**/folder/ → example.com/folder/
- Query parameters should be preserved

I already have a rewrite rule that does the job:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^not/needed(.*)$ $1 [L,R=302,QSA]
```

However after the rewrite has been made, I get 404. How can I tell the server it should show the content from the original URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule only works in one direction. `RewriteRule <target> <destination>`, there's no magic that makes it go in reverse. You need to *explicitly* create a rule that does the opposite:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+not/needed/(.*)
RewriteRule ^not/needed(.*)$ $1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/not/needed/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /not/needed/$1 [L]
```